# Android add <item> to style programmatically

Tags: android

I have my custom style

```
<style name="my_style" parent="@style/parent_style">
        <item name="custom_color">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

and applying it to some view.

I'm using code:
 
`final ContextThemeWrapper ctw= new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.my_theme);
View view = new View(ctw)`

Is it possible to add this custom_color attribute dynamically from code?
something like ctw.addAttr...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add items during runtime. All data in the `/res` folder can't be modified because the ADT builds the R class out of the data while compiling.

Comment: Ok I assumed that. Thank you!